# selected UIButton image

Tags: ios, uibutton

I need to toggle an image (on or off). When I set the default (in interface builder) it works, however when I add a selected image nothing happens.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: gotta set your button to selected in order for it to show button.selected=TRUE;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added a UIButton class to control the images of the button (custom subclass of UIButton)